# Ionic : Data is not getting fetched after initial load in Android works fine in browser

Tags: android, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm developing booking app using ionic 5.

Issue is happening only in android devices (ios no idea)

When user comes for fist time and booked and navigates to booking history, data is displayed.

Again user books another item, now when he visits booking history latest entry is not displaying but in browser view it is working fine.

How to fix this issue ? please guide.

Booking History Component

```
  ngOnInit () {
    this.loaderService.showLoader();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.getUserData(user.uid);
      }
    })
  }


  getUserData (uid) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).once("value", snap => {
      let data = snap.val();
      let bookings = [];

      for (let key of Object.keys(data.bookings)) {
        let booking = data.bookings[key];
        booking.bookedDate = new Date(booking.bookedDate).toDateString();
        bookings.push(booking);
      }
      this.bookingHistory = bookings;
      this.loaderService.hideLoader();
      console.log(this.bookingHistory);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an life cycle problem, your view is not being destroy and it only fetch the data from the first initialization on the `ngOnInit`. Try calling your data on the `ionViewDidEnter` event like so:

```
 ionViewDidEnter(){
      this.loaderService.showLoader();
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          this.getUserData(user.uid);
        }
      });
   }
```

You can check more about life cycle from the official docs [Here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#ionic-page-events)